# Max width not working with flexbox+align-items: center

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper that make everything in center:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

But because of `align-items: center` components inside wrapper with max-width gets shrinked for some reason.

How can i fix this preferable without touching wrapper?

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/styled-components-qqkos

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
const Component = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;
const Input = styled.input`
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
`;
const Button = styled.button``;
const App = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Component>
      <Input type="text" />
      <Button>ClickMe</Button>
    </Component>
  </Wrapper>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem can be solved like this:

```
const Component = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
`;
```